# Processing Javascript RegEx submatches

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I am trying to write some JavaScript RegEx to replace user inputed tags with real html tags, so `[b]` will become `<b>` and so forth. the RegEx I am using looks like so

```
var exptags = /\[(b|u|i|s|center|code){1}]((.){1,}?)\[\/(\1){1}]/ig;
```

with the following JavaScript

```
s.replace(exptags,"<$1>$2</$1>");
```

this works fine for single nested tags, for example:

```
[b]hello[/b] [u]world[/u]
```

but if the tags are nested inside each other it will only match the outer tags, for example

```
[b]foo [u]to the[/u] bar[/b]
```

this will only match the `b` tags. how can I fix this? should i just loop until the starting string is the same as the outcome? I have a feeling that the `((.){1,}?)` patten is wrong also?

Thanks

Comment: I can't believe no one has left this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/20074

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to to replace all the tags, whether they are closed or not and let `.innerHTML` work out if they are matched or not it will much more resilient that way..

```
var tagreg = /\[(\/?)(b|u|i|s|center|code)]/ig
div.innerHTML="[b][i]helloworld[/b]".replace(tagreg, "<$1$2>") //no closing i
//div.inerHTML=="<b><i>helloworld</i></b>"
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't express recursion with regular expressions.

You can however do that with .NET's System.Text.RegularExpressions using balanced matching. See more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx

If you're using .NET you can probably implement what you need with a callback. 
If not, you may have to roll your own little javascript parser.

Then again, if you can afford to hit the server you can use the full parser. :)

What do you need this for, anyway? If it is for anything other than a preview I highly recommend doing the processing server-side.

Comment: Yes its for a live preview for a comments area, server side its PHP, but  have the code for that bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to loop. Alternatively since your tags looks so much like HTML ones you could replace `[b]` for `<b>` and `[/b]` for `</b>` separately. (.){1,}? is the same as (.*?) - that is, any symbols, least possible sequence length.

Updated: Thanks to MrP, (.){1,}? is (.)+?, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the inner pattern being troublesome.

```
((.){1,}?)
```

That is doing a captured match at least once and then the whole thing is captured. Every character inside your tag will be captured as a group.

You are also capturing your closing element name when you don't need it and are using `{1}` when that is implied. Below is a cleanup up version:

```
/\[(b|u|i|s|center|code)](.+?)\[\/\1]/ig
```

Not sure about the other problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could just repeatedly apply the regexp until it no longer matches. That would do odd things like "[b][b]foo[/b][/b]" => "<b>[b]foo</b>[/b]" => "<b><b>foo</b></b>", but as far as I can see the end result will still be a sensible string with matching (though not necessarily properly nested) tags.

Or if you want to do it 'right', just write a simple recursive descent parser. Though people might expect "[b]foo[u]bar[/b]baz[/u]" to work, which is tricky to recognise with a parser.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the nested block doesn't get replaced is because the match, for [b], places the position after [/b]. Thus, everything that ((.){1,}?) matches is then ignored.

It is possible to write a recursive parser in server-side -- Perl uses [qr//](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html) and Ruby probably has something similar.

Though, you don't necessarily need true recursive. You can use a relatively simple loop to handle the string equivalently:

```
var s = '[b]hello[/b] [u]world[/u] [b]foo [u]to the[/u] bar[/b]';
var exptags = /\[(b|u|i|s|center|code){1}]((.){1,}?)\[\/(\1){1}]/ig;

while (s.match(exptags)) {
   s = s.replace(exptags, "<$1>$2</$1>");
}

document.writeln('<div>' + s + '</div>'); // after
```

In this case, it'll make 2 passes:

```
0: [b]hello[/b] [u]world[/u] [b]foo [u]to the[/u] bar[/b]
1: <b>hello</b> <u>world</u> <b>foo [u]to the[/u] bar</b>
2: <b>hello</b> <u>world</u> <b>foo <u>to the</u> bar</b>
```

---

Also, a few suggestions for cleaning up the RegEx:

```
var exptags = /\[(b|u|i|s|center|code)\](.+?)\[\/(\1)\]/ig;
```

- {1} is assumed when no other count specifiers exist
- {1,} can be shortened to +

Comment: If you add [center][/center] to your test case, and nest one tag inside another, and take my regex from below, I'll vote your answer up.

Comment: By "nest one tag inside another", I meant "the same tag inside itself", for example: [b] foo [b]bar[/b] baz[/b]

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Richard Szalay, but his regex didn't get quoted right:

```
var exptags = /\[(b|u|i|s|center|code)](.*)\[\/\1]/ig;
```

is cleaner.  Note that I also change `.+?` to `.*`.  There are two problems with `.+?`:

1. you won't match [u][/u], since there isn't at least one character between them (+)
2. a non-greedy match won't deal as nicely with the same tag nested inside itself (?)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
tagreg=/\[(.?)?(b|u|i|s|center|code)\]/gi;
"[b][i]helloworld[/i][/b]".replace(tagreg, "<$1$2>");
"[b]helloworld[/b]".replace(tagreg, "<$1$2>");
```

For me the above produces:

```
<b><i>helloworld</i></b>
<b>helloworld</b>
```

This appears to do what you want, and has the advantage of needing only a single pass.

Disclaimer: I don't code often in JS, so if I made any mistakes please feel free to point them out :-)